# Mezzanine search engine

Tags: django, search, case-sensitive, mezzanine

I use [Mezzanine CMS](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/). It has {% search_form "app.model" %} template tag, it works fine, but it case-sensitive search. How can I make case-insensitive search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mezzanine's search is already case insensitive.